# Call external executable from NPAPI on OS X?

Tags: macos, system, npapi

I'm developing an application (download manager-type) on OS X that I would like to integrate with the major Mac browers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Camino) via the Mozilla plug-in API, NPAPI. I have a basic understanding of how to register my app on the Mac to handle specific URL's and file types (via the Launch Services API, the info.plist file, etc.), and I also understand that I can register for specific MIME types in the NPAPI. However, I see almost no hooks in the NPAPI docs for integration with external applications, i.e. getting a URL via `NPN_GetURL()` when a hyperlink is clicked and passing this data on to an external application. The only references I've found to calling external applications is the `system` function in C, and I'm finding it hard to believe this is the only way it can be done. I know that other Mac apps (download managers) are able to integrate with browsers in this fashion, but there seems to be very little documentation about it. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the NPAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual API of NPAPI is very limited; much of what plugins do they do through direct system calls. `system` isn't your only option—you can use anything you would use any any OS X application (`NSWorkspace`, Apple Events, IPC to a `launchd`-registered service, etc.)—but you won't find a call in NPAPI to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are misunderstanding NPAPIs purpose. For things like intercepting clicking of links and changing the browsers behavior you need to write [browser extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_extension), not a plugin.

See:

- [Plug-ins and extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29#Plug-ins_and_extensions)
- [Browser Plugins vs Extensions – the difference](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/)